# Selenium driver version // get_capabilities()

Tags: perl, google-chrome, selenium, internet-explorer, firefox

my selenium scripts (written in perl) are using/running on firefox, chrome and IE as i expected them to do. I wrote my own "Testrun logging" which is also fine. A few day ago, i had the idea to include the selenium driver version.
The selenium standalone server version is available via "$driver->status". If my scripts are running on chrome i found the version info via "$driver->get_capabilities()". But for ie i havn't found a version number.
For chrome i geht a hash like:

```
{
    acceptSslCerts               JSON::PP::Boolean  {
        Parents                  Types::Serialiser::BooleanBase
        public methods (0)
        private methods (0)
        internals: 1
    },
    applicationCacheEnabled      JSON::PP::Boolean  {
        Parents                  Types::Serialiser::BooleanBase
        public methods (0)
        private methods (0)
        internals: 0
    },
    browserConnectionEnabled     var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    browserName                  "chrome",
    chrome                       {
        chromedriverVersion      "2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed)",
        userDataDir              "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8684_28008"
    },
    cssSelectorsEnabled          var{acceptSslCerts},
    databaseEnabled              var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    handlesAlerts                var{acceptSslCerts},
    hasTouchScreen               var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    javascriptEnabled            var{acceptSslCerts},
    locationContextEnabled       var{acceptSslCerts},
    mobileEmulationEnabled       var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    nativeEvents                 var{acceptSslCerts},
    networkConnectionEnabled     var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    pageLoadStrategy             "normal",
    platform                     "XP",
    rotatable                    var{applicationCacheEnabled},
    takesHeapSnapshot            var{acceptSslCerts},
    takesScreenshot              var{acceptSslCerts},
    version                      "54.0.2840.99",
    webdriver.remote.sessionid   "eb545ef9-6a1b-4297-a239-ca595bafbec1",
    webStorageEnabled            var{acceptSslCerts}
}
```

for ie i get:

```
{
    browserAttachTimeout            0,
    browserName                     "internet explorer",
    cssSelectorsEnabled             JSON::PP::Boolean  {
        Parents                     Types::Serialiser::BooleanBase
        public methods (0)
        private methods (0)
        internals: 1
    },
    elementScrollBehavior           0,
    enableElementCacheCleanup       var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    enablePersistentHover           var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    ie.browserCommandLineSwitches   "",
    ie.enableFullPageScreenshot     var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    ie.ensureCleanSession           JSON::PP::Boolean  {
        Parents                     Types::Serialiser::BooleanBase
        public methods (0)
        private methods (0)
        internals: 0
    },
    ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout      3000,
    ie.forceCreateProcessApi        var{ie.ensureCleanSession},
    ie.forceShellWindowsApi         var{ie.ensureCleanSession},
    ignoreProtectedModeSettings     var{ie.ensureCleanSession},
    ignoreZoomSetting               var{ie.ensureCleanSession},
    initialBrowserUrl               "http://localhost:48881/",
    javascriptEnabled               var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    nativeEvents                    var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    pageLoadStrategy                "normal",
    platform                        "WINDOWS",
    requireWindowFocus              var{ie.ensureCleanSession},
    takesScreenshot                 var{cssSelectorsEnabled},
    unexpectedAlertBehaviour        "dismiss",
    version                         11,
    webdriver.remote.sessionid      "b630495e-70fe-4d68-b4e4-cb24a57acab3"
}
```

but here is nothing like "chromedriverVersion".
Does anyone know a way how to get the version of the IEDriver?

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not quite sure whether you're looking to log the version of the WebDriver or the version of the browser. If the latter, the version is printed in both of the outputs in your question.

If you're looking to log the webdriver version, it doesn't look like IE driver has  driver version in the list of capabilities (see: [DesiredCapabilities documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) and [ChromeDriver Capabilities documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)). As far as I can tell, the properties listed on those pages are the only ones you can read from a WebDriver.

You could try (in Java, but I imagine the method is similar in Perl)

```
driver.getCapability("InternetExplorerDriver.version"); // or something like this,
```

but as far as I can tell, there's no IE driver version available to query.

Comment: I'm looking for the driver version not the browser version. For the IEDriver i expected to get 2.53.1, but as the doku you linked did not mention the driver version for IEDriver, i did not expect to get it somehow